# Serializing models to a json field in Rails using active_model_serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization

I have a Task model that looks like this:

```
class Task
   # has a title
   belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
   belongs_to :asignee, class_name: "User
end
```

And a Sprint with a json field `metadata`:

```
create_table :sprints, id: :uuid do |t|
  t.json :metadata
end

class Sprint
    def close_sprint
        self.metadata = serialized_tasks
        self.save
    end
end
```

I'm using active model serializers to serialize `sprint tasks` like this:

```
def serialized_tasks
   ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(self.tasks, serializer: TaskSerializer).to_json
end
```

The problem is that it stores the tasks data as a `json string` and not as a json object.

The serializer looks like this:

```
class TaskSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :title, :owner_name, :created_at, :status, :asignee_name, :asignee_email

  def owner_name
    object&.owner&.full_name
  end

  def asignee_name
    object&.asignee&.full_name
  end

  def asignee_email
    object&.asignee&.email
  end
end
```

How can I get a valid JSON object to be stored in a rails json field using active_model_serializers? If it's not possible, how can I query the associated data as a valid JSON object to store in the `metadata` field?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the hash I needed using `as_json` instead of `to_json`.

> as_json(options = nil)
>
> Returns a hash representing the model. Some
>   configuration can be passed through options.
>
> The option include_root_in_json controls the top-level behavior of
>   as_json. If true, as_json will emit a single root node named after the
>   object's type. The default value for include_root_in_json option is
>   false.